# Building a minimal HAProxy VM. Where to start?

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, hyper-v, haproxy

I want to build a minimal VM (in Hyper-V on Windows 2008 R2) that runs HAProxy to load balance a bunch of web services.

Is there a preferred Linux distribution that provides a small, yet functional environment from which to build the HAProxy balancer.  And obviously, the Linux distribution would have to work in Hyper-V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, any of the common distributions should work fine.  I've used Debian and Ubuntu Server, but that's only because it's what I'm familiar with.  That's probably the best answer - stick with what you know.

If you don't have a ton of linux experience, Ubuntu Server or CentOS are probably decent choices, as they have good documentation and package managers.

Comment: +1 this is pretty much what I would have said. There are a couple of cases where you might want to look at a hardened version or for some particular performance specialism, but for most general cases the base install plus a few packages is going to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks.  I picked Ubuntu.  Seems to work fine with just 1GB RAM.